# How to specify the loss function when finetuning a model using the Huggingface TFTrainer Class?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I have followed the basic example as given below, from: https://huggingface.co/transformers/training.html

```
from transformers import TFBertForSequenceClassification, TFTrainer, TFTrainingArguments

model = TFBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("bert-large-uncased")

training_args = TFTrainingArguments(
    output_dir='./results',          # output directory
    num_train_epochs=3,              # total # of training epochs
    per_device_train_batch_size=16,  # batch size per device during training
    per_device_eval_batch_size=64,   # batch size for evaluation
    warmup_steps=500,                # number of warmup steps for learning rate scheduler
    weight_decay=0.01,               # strength of weight decay
    logging_dir='./logs',            # directory for storing logs
)

trainer = TFTrainer(
    model=model,                         # the instantiated  Transformers model to be trained
    args=training_args,                  # training arguments, defined above
    train_dataset=tfds_train_dataset,    # tensorflow_datasets training dataset
    eval_dataset=tfds_test_dataset       # tensorflow_datasets evaluation dataset
)
trainer.train()
```

But there seems to be no way to specify the loss function for the classifier. For-ex if I finetune on a binary classification problem, I would use

```
tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
```

else I would use

```
tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
```

My set up is as follows:

```
transformers==4.3.2
tensorflow==2.3.1
python==3.6.12
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Trainer` has this capability to use `compute_loss`

For more you can look into the documentation:
[https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/trainer#:~:text=passed%20at%20init.-,compute_loss,-%2D%20Computes%20the%20loss](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/trainer#:%7E:text=passed%20at%20init.-,compute_loss,-%2D%20Computes%20the%20loss)

Here is an example of how to customize Trainer to use a weighted loss (useful when you have an unbalanced training set):

```
from torch import nn
from transformers import Trainer


class CustomTrainer(Trainer):
    def compute_loss(self, model, inputs, return_outputs=False):
        labels = inputs.get("labels")
        # forward pass
        outputs = model(**inputs)
        logits = outputs.get("logits")
        # compute custom loss (suppose one has 3 labels with different weights)
        loss_fct = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=torch.tensor([1.0, 2.0, 3.0]))
        loss = loss_fct(logits.view(-1, self.model.config.num_labels), labels.view(-1))
        return (loss, outputs) if return_outputs else loss
```

Comment: Choosing this as the right answer because it contains some code demonstration.

Answer (score 3):

create a class which inherits from PreTrainedModel and then in it's forward function create your respective loss function.

Comment: What you suggested works fine :) but I would love some minimally running code so as for it to be illustrative to future newbies (and me perhaps).